# how to fix unknown prop zdepth warning when using with reactjs , material ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

warning.js:36Warning: Unknown prop `zDepth` on  tag. Remove this prop from the element.

I am trying to render a . But it is showing the above error. Can any one help please ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import Divider from 'material-ui/Divider'; 
import paper from 'material-ui/Paper'; 
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme'; 
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'; 
import baseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/lightBaseTheme';

export default class EmploymentContent extends Component { 
  getChildContext() { 
    return { muiTheme: getMuiTheme(baseTheme) }; 
  } 

  render() { 
    return ( 
      <paper zDepth={4}> <ul className="scroll"> </paper>
    ...
```

Comment: what about show us some code?

Comment: import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Divider from 'material-ui/Divider';
import paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import baseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/lightBaseTheme';export default class EmploymentContent extends Component {

    getChildContext() {
        return { muiTheme: getMuiTheme(baseTheme) };
    }  
    render() {
        return (  <paper zDepth={4}>
        <ul className="scroll"> </paper>

Comment: material ui version?

Comment: material ui version is 0.16.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing this warning because you are using the `Paper` component with **lowercase** and React treats these lowercase tags as built-in components.

All you need to do is import and use it as `Paper`, starting with the capital letter.

> When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a
>   built-in component like  or  and results in a string 'div'
>   or 'span' passed to React.createElement. Types that start with a
>   capital letter like  compile to React.createElement(Foo) and
>   correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.
>
> We recommend naming components with a capital letter. If you do have a
>   component that starts with a lowercase letter, assign it to a
>   capitalized variable before using it in JSX.

You can see it here
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized

There is also an issue open https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7848 to add it on the `unknown-props` warning page.